# What does entity.Items.Clear() do in EF?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In a project I'm working on, whenever I call `SaveChanges()` after clearing list of items, I get this error:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because
>   one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a
>   change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is
>   set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values,
>   a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be
>   assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be
>   deleted.

I have these two classes with one to many relationship (simplest implementation):

```
public class Company
{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public virtual List<Vehicle> Vehicles {get; set;}
}

public class Vehicle
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Model {get; set;}

}
```

I'm guessing that calling `company.Vehicles.Clear()` should update the auto generated column `Company_Id` in the Vehicle table, setting its value to null, but that not seems the case which the error above indicating.
So I'me wondering what exactly `company.Vehicles.Clear()` do in the database side?

**EDIT**

Thanks to the answer by @McKabue and the link he provided, I found this is the solution, this is the complete code:

```
var company = context.Set<GENCompany>().
                        Include(m => m.Vehicles).
                        Include(m => m.Quotes).
                        Include(m => m.Phones).
                        Include(m => m.Persons).
                        Include(m => m.Leads).
                        Include(m => m.Emails).
                        Include(m => m.Drivers).
                        Include(m => m.Deals).
                        Include(m => m.Comments).
                        Include(m => m.Branches).
                        Include(m => m.Addresses).
                        SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == companyModel.Id);

                    context.Entry(company).State = EntityState.Modified;

                    company.Vehicles.Clear();
                    company.Drivers.Clear();
                    company.Quotes.Clear();
                    company.Persons.Clear();
                    company.Leads.Clear();
                    company.Deals.Clear();
                    company.Branches.Clear();

                    var phones = context.CompanyPhones.Where(x => x.CompanyId == companyModel.Id);
                    context.CompanyPhones.RemoveRange(phones);

                    var emails = context.CompanyEmails.Where(x => x.CompanyId == companyModel.Id);
                    context.CompanyEmails.RemoveRange(emails);

                    var comments = context.CompanyComments.Where(x => x.CompanyId == companyModel.Id);
                    context.CompanyComments.RemoveRange(comments);

                    var addresses = context.CompanyAddresses.Where(x => x.CompanyId == companyModel.Id);
                    context.CompanyAddresses.RemoveRange(addresses);
```

For some entities they are removed using .Clear() syntax, other entities are removed by fetching their records and deleteing them all (not only the relation). It makes perfect sense in the current design, for example in the create page of the company, the phone data is added manually, while vehicles are selected from drop down menu, while it makes this perfect sense I feel so confused to determine why this happen, for example here is the CompanyPhone class:

```
 public class GENCompanyPhone
    {
        [Key]
        public long PhoneId { get; set; }
        public long CompanyId { get; set; }
        public long PhoneTypeId { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public Guid? CreatedById { get; set; }
        public bool IsPublish { get; set; } = false;
        public bool IsActive { get; set; } = false;

        [MaxLength(255)]
        [Index(IsUnique = true)]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
        public virtual GENCompany Company { get; set; }
    }
```

on the other hand this is the vehicle class:

```
public class GENVehicle
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public long? BrandId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("BrandId")]
        public GENBrand Brand { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LicenseIssueDate { get; set; }

        public Guid? CreatedById { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("VehicleTypeId")]
        public virtual GENVehicleType VehicleType { get; set; }
        public long? VehicleTypeId { get; set; }    
        public long? LicenseIssuerId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("LicenseIssuerId")]
        public GENEmployee LicenseIssuer { get; set; }

    }
```

I can't determine exactly why EF deal differently with `Vehicle` and `CompanyPhone`

Answer (score 1):

It means that you are clearing a record that is referenced in another table. So, EF warns you...there are ways you can avoid this by setting [Cascade delete](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php)

**Edit**
To remove child elements from a parent table, the children entities need to be loaded.

**Edit 2**

```
var company = context.Set<GENCompany>().Where(m => m.Id == companyModel.Id);
                        Include(m => m.Vehicles).
                        Include(m => m.Quotes).
                        Include(m => m.Phones).
                        Include(m => m.Persons).
                        Include(m => m.Leads).
                        Include(m => m.Emails).
                        Include(m => m.Drivers).
                        Include(m => m.Deals).
                        Include(m => m.Comments).
                        Include(m => m.Branches).
                        Include(m => m.Addresses).SingleOrDefault();




                    company.Vehicles.Clear();
                    company.Drivers.Clear();
                    company.Quotes.Clear();
                    company.Persons.Clear();
                    company.Leads.Clear();
                    company.Deals.Clear();
                    company.Branches.Clear();
```

THAT WILL WORK

1. Query before Including
2. Include All entities you want to remove;
3. Clear / RemoveRange / Remove one by one from the parent (company object)

Comment: I don't want to delete the record, I just want to revoke the relationship by setting the foreign key to null

Comment: In this answer he removed the entity then the child elements, I want to remove child elements and update the parent

Comment: Please see the amended answer, If you could help? is this happen because I set the foreign key in the PhoneCompany class?

Comment: setting foreign keys in the class doesn't affect anything, unless you are doing a many-to-many relationship with entity framework core

Comment: Why did you copy/paste my code?! it wasn't an answer !

Comment: You didn't explain the code, you just described it!